# How do we avoid file naming conflicts between windows and linux users in Git?

Tags: linux, windows, git

In linux `>` is a valid filename character. This is not outrageous to see in the context of Jupyter notebooks.

A linux user can commit this file to a git repo.

If a windows user then syncs the git repo they'll end up with an error because `>` is not a valid file name in windows.

Given a shared repository where Jupyter notebooks reside and windows and linux users coexist, is there an optimal/convenient/safe/organized way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to add git hooks that warns or even stops the user comitting or pushing the code.